Horror Film about a streamer convention set at a hotel where a tragedy had taken place
I ran into this Reddit question while trying to research something else. They mentioned this:

I’ve searched a lot for the one big thing I remember but I can’t find anything on it and that is, "kill con". It was something about a big event but deaths keep happening making the title or something kill con. I also remember and I’m not sure about this but I remember there may have been some ghost girl.

They wound up accepting an answer, but another film came to mind that my wife and I watched, I'm pretty sure on Netflix, definitely within the last decade, but probably about 3-5 years ago, prior to our toddler being born. The premise of the film is that a convention for influencers/streamers is being held in a hotel that, unbeknownst to them, is haunted. One of the symbols of the haunting is mascot in a bunny costume. My brain wants to say the rabbit is pink, but I might be channeling Robbie the Rabbit from Silent Hill. As per the Reddit post, I do remember the balloon being a recurring motif, although I don't recall if it was involved in a kill. I think there was a recurring visual motif that the hotel had a mold problem, symbolism of deep-seated rot in society being painted over without fixing the problem and so on. Other than that, my brain has several isolated scenes:

At the beginning, there's a teletype display, like with an old-fashioned BBS. It might have been paired up with an early murder, which was the start of the haunting?
Earlyish in the film, there's a series of scenes showing the various influencers descending a double staircase, probably in the lobby of the hotel, with them obviously posing for cameras and filming footage for their channel.
At some point, it's either shown or highly implied that a cleaning lady (Hispanic?) is killed by the evil.
I think there was a possession motif where whatever was haunting the motel took over one or more of the main characters, pushing them to violent impulses.
The end of the film implied that the evil had survived, and might have made it onto the internet.


In the process of writing the question, the name "deadcon" came to mind, and indeed, Deadcon was a 2019 horror film (a rather critically panned one):

Deadcon is a 2019 horror film directed by Caryn Waechter and starring real-life YouTube personalities Lauren Elizabeth and Claudia Sulewski as AKAshley and Megan, two of the main draws at Viewcon, a convention for YouTube personalities. Ashley is wanting to get out the limelight, but her manager Kara (Mimi Gianopulos) doesn't want to lose hold of the lightning in a bottle they've captured together. Megan is grappling with her attraction to gaming livecaster Dave (Keith Machekanyanga), but has yet to break up with her boyfriend, Ricky. Meanwhile, a double-booking has resulted in Ashley being roomed next door to Megan in suite 2210A, which may be haunted by the ghost of Bobby, and the malevolent spirit of the founder of the failed 1984 internet chat service, Linkrabbit...


You can just tell by the plot that the director was hoping to get Youtube viewership numbers for ticket sales.

Donnie not-so-Darko...
